# Inheritance of properties

Tags: system-verilog

Is it possible to inherit some properties from the scope that we invoke a function? A code snippet might help more to explain:

```
typedef enum logic {
    RESET    , IDLE   ,
    STATE_A  , STATE_B} states;
//as you see above I don't define the width or the values of the states

states current_state, next_state;

  always_comb begin
    assign next_state = next_state_func (
      curr_state,    reset,
      modportA.some_signal_a, modportA.some_signal_b);
  end

function next_state_func (
      //THIS IS THE BUG ZONE:
      //Can I inherit the caller's signals properties? I mean I don't have specific width available so what do I do? 
      ref curr_state,    ref reset,
      ref some_signal_a, ref some_signal_b);

  endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the LRM on functions and pass by reference

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 13.4 *Functions*:

> It shall be illegal to call a function with output, inout, or ref arguments in an event expression, in an expression within a procedural continuous assignment, or in an expression that is not within a procedural statement. However, a const ref function argument shall be legal in this context (see 13.5.2).

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 13.5.2 *Pass by reference*:

> Arguments passed by reference are not copied into the subroutine area, rather, a reference to the original argument is passed to the subroutine. The subroutine can then access the argument data via the reference. Arguments passed by reference shall be matched with equivalent data types (see 6.22.2). No casting shall be permitted. To indicate argument passing by reference, the argument declaration is preceded by the `ref` keyword. It shall be illegal to use argument passing by reference for subroutines with a lifetime of `static`. The general syntax is as follows:
>   `subroutine( ref type argument );`

You can try:

```
function automatic states next_state_func (
  const ref states curr_state,
  const ref logic reset,
  const ref {type} some_signal_a,
  const ref {type} some_signal_b);
...
endfunction
```

I'm not sure if it can synthesize. I haven't seen any documentation that give guidance on functions with `ref` synthesize. I always use `ref` for test-bench related area. When coding RTL, I calculate the `next_state` inside an `always_comb` without any `function` calls.

---

Other issue:
Do not put `assign` inside procedural blocks. Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § C.4.2 *Procedural assign and deassign statements*

> The procedural `assign` and `deassign` statements can be a source of design errors and can be an impediment to tool implementation. The procedural `assign` and `deassign` statements do not provide a capability that cannot be done by another method that avoids these problems. Therefore, the procedural `assign` and `deassign` statements are on a deprecation list. ...
>
> ...
>
> Allowing the `assign` statement to be used both inside and outside a procedural block causes confusion and is a source of errors in SystemVerilog models. The practice of using the `assign` and `deassign` statements inside procedural blocks is highly discouraged.

Your code should be:

```
always_comb begin
  next_state = ...
end
```

or

```
assign next_state = ...
```

Comment: OK, I'll avoid calling a function you're right. Is there a way to inherit/pass a signal's width implicitly?

Comment: I don't know of any way to pass unknown widths that is still synthesizable. Physical hardward cannot have unknown signals widths and HDL reflects that. You can create `typedef`s, bundle the signals in `struct`s, `union`s, and `interface`s. Another methods is to create a parameterize function, which is done via a parameterized class with a static function (this is the one condition something from a class can synthesize); [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22711967/1959732).